# -webkit-calc() in Chrome for Mobile

Tags: android, google-chrome

I would like to use -webkit-calc() on Chrome for Android, but it doesn't seem to be available 
Is that correct?
How do I get information on webkit feature support?

Comment: This tells about most other browsers, but not sure about android chrome: http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: Unfortunately Chrome Mobile is not listed yet.

Comment: you can see Android's Chrome support in the "full version": http://caniuse.com/calc

Answer (score 1):

A little late to answer the question, but Chrome for Android was on M16 and M18 for quite a long time which didn't have any support for -webkit-calc.  As of M25 -webkit-calc is now available

We talked about it in our latest video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eHKebsEOns&feature=player_detailpage#t=72s3

I also created a simple demo at http://jsbin.com/esepeq/latest that you can see it in action on any browser that supports it.

Comment: Hey I'm running Chrome M27 on a Nexus 7 and calc still isnt working.  I've used your test site as well as others but they dont seem to be working.  Any update here? Thanks.

Comment: Turns out I had to manually do an update and now it works!  Sorry for any alarm.

Comment: No worries, the not updating Chrome on Android is a problem :\